# See the version of the services that are installed

Tags: powershell, service, windows-services, powershell-cmdlet

I want to see the version numbers of the services that are installed on my PC via PowerShell. But it only shows me Status, Name, DisplayName. How can I see the version numbers of services using PowerShell. Below you can see the code that I'm using. (I want to see the versions of the services that has the word "Arda" in it, because of that I use `-Name "Arda*"` parameter.

`Get-Service -Name 'Arda*'`

Comment: Is it available in the result of Get-Service? If not you're looking in the wrong place. It can be checked using Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product

Comment: It's not available in the result of Get-Service. I'm pretty new in PowerShell, Can you further explain Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product? Thank you.

Comment: Important: why [**not to query `Win32_Product`**](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/).

Comment: See if you can find the executable path using `(Get-cimInstance -ClassName win32_service -Filter 'Name like "%Arda%"').PathName` and get the FileVersion from that